# My Browser won't interpret "ΧΨ" when I load the website I'm building

Tags: html, css

I pretty much built this website in firebug, then when I copied the code into a text document and tried loading it, firefox wouldn't interpret the "ΧΨ" in the source. However, it does a fantastic job using them while I'm typing this.

Wassup wid dat?

Comment: How should firefox interpret those characters in the source of a website? Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just type a character into an HTML tag, it must be a valid character and if not use the proper character code. See this list:
http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html

You can use Entity, Decimal, or Hex to represent your character like this:

```
<p>&Chi;&Psi;</p>
```

That's the HTML representation of "ΧΨ"

Cheers

Comment: That's not actually true.  You can type whatever you want in as text (with the obvious exception of `<` and `&`), as long as you then indicate to the browser what encoding you used when converting the Unicode file you typed in to bytes so it can reverse the conversion and get the same Unicode you were typing in.

Comment: This is true, but when it comes to these special characters it is the best practice to use the character code as oppose to changing the encoding of the page which can affect other elements. Changing encoding is a more advance step from my point of view that a person just begging should not be doing.

Comment: Yeah, fair.  For what it's worth, the encoding issue is almost certainly what's causing Breedly current problem.